# What is the equivalent of \usetocstyle in tocbasic

Tags: tocstyle, tocbasic

Miktex considers the tocstyle package to be obsolete and suggests using tocbasic instead. However, with tocbasic I get undefined control sequence at \usetocstyle. I found that \DeclareTOCStyleEntries exists, but it seems to have a much more complicated syntax. Is there a straightforward replacement for the \usetocstyle command?